# Cannot resolve symbol AndroidSchedulers

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm using version 2.0.0 of RxJava, and it seems like I have no access to `AndroidSchedulers`. I'm unable to get access to mainthread through RxJava

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`AndroidSchedulers` class is a part of [`RxAndroid`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) library. Add it to your app's `build.gradle`:

before Gradle v3.0:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

since Gradle v3.0:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
```

Answer (score 9):

I had same problem. You cannot call AndroidSchedulers with RxJava3. I think this is a bug. They need to fix it.

*You need to add they on your dependencies of gradle:*

```
//RxAndroid
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'

//RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.10'
```

Comment: I had the same issue.  For RxJava3,  it looks like you need both the rxjava3 and rxandroid3 implementation.`implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.1.1"
    implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0"`

Answer (score 8):

Go back to Old Versions:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'   
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.6'
```

Then to the Newer Version:

```
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'    
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.1'
```

Sounds Weird but it works

Comment: This is perfectly working, thanks a lot. This is more meaningful and helpful answer

Answer (score 2):

```
def rxJavaVersion = '2.1.1'

//Add to dependencies the following libraries

dependencies {

  implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rxJavaVersion"

  implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rxJavaVersion"

}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use RX 3 by adding the below dependency

```
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:$version"
```

get the version from this link : https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Comment: `io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0`